# Running a python application across enterprise without install

Tags: python

Company I work for has a python based application that takes an excel template as an input performs some manipulation and then outputs an excel file.

Our current setup requires all users to have python and the correct packages installed.

I want users to be able to run this script without having to install python.

I've looked into potentially setting up a virtual environment on one of the shared drives available to all users / creating a flask web app to input the template.

I'm looking for any suggestions on whether this would be viable / any better methods / any issues I might encounter using this approach.

Comment: Consider using `pyinstaller` https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/ to build some executables. It will contain all dependencies so users will have to download only one executable.

Comment: That sounds like a simple app. I would put it on a webpage - make life for everyone pretty easy: updates in one place - accessible from everywhere.

Comment: I would use an azure function or microsoft flow that gets triggered when a file is added to a given sharepoint folder. But that's just because we already have licences and use these products. A flask app is fine as well